# Powershell script rename music files

Tags: shell, powershell

I have a lot of music file like this:

"01 - Chan Chan - Buena Vista Social Club"

or

"03.In Your Own Sweet Way"

I want to make a script on how to delete 
the "01 -" or the "03."

But I have no idea on how to make this
because all of my files are different (sometimes "0.1" or "0.01")
I just want to remove all the numbers in front of the song
so if I put it in my music library I don't have the stupid numbers in front of them...

Anyone that can help?

Comment: Are the actual song names always preceded by a "." or "-"?  If so, you should be able to split the string on those characters.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `Get-ChildItem` to list all files in a given directory.
- Include the `-Recurse` switch if you want to include sub directories.
- Include the `-File` switch so we only rename files
- Include a filter if you only want to match some files in the directory
- Use a regex replace to filter out unwanted characters (e.g. with `(\d*\s*[\.-]?\s*\d*)(.*)` the first capturing group will collect any numbers (including 1 optional decimal point or hyphen (and any surrounding whitespace) within the number), and the second will capture everything else; then we just keep that second part).
- Use `Rename-Item` to update the filename

.

```
clear-host 
$myMusicDirectory = 'c:\music\'
$extension = '*.mp3'

Get-ChildItem -Path $myMusicDirectory -Recurse -Filter $extension -file | %{
    $newName = $_.Name -replace '(\d*\s*[\.-]?\s*\d*)(.*)','$2'
    rename-item -Path $_.PSPath -NewName $newName
}
```

Comment: It works but could you check my comment below please thanks